# Aumentar Velocidad al ejecutar aplicación en .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Como evitar que al ejecutar el programa en ***.NET 2008*** evitar que me genere el .exe y asi ganar velocidad en la ejecución.

Ya he probado a quitar el check en esta ventana.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando quito el check en la columna ***Generar*** no me tiene en cuenta los últimos cambios realizados.

Habría alguna manera de poder hacerlo ?

Comment: si no generas el exe que quieres ejecutar? a que te referis con mayor velocidad?

Comment: Tengo un proyecto donde tengo más de 70 formularios, cada vez que cambio una coma, se tiene que volver a compilar todo de nuevo, y el equipo donde trabajo no es muy moderno... Sé que en la versión vb6, no me genera el .exe cada vez que compruebo lo que he hecho, queria saber si en la versión 2008 y 2012 se puede cambiar de alguna manera

Comment: y es correcto.. probablemente deberias ver si el proyecto se puede dividir en librerias o algo asi.. pero si tiene que compilar todo.. es un solo exe, debe empaquetarlo todo junto.